# Read all nodes value in root with there attribute through linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have following structure of XML doc which is return by some web rest API in xml format .

```
-<spls>
 -<metadata>    
   <total_elements>4056</total_elements>
   <elements_per_page>100</elements_per_page>
   <total_pages>41</total_pages>
   <current_page>1</current_page>
   <current_url>https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v2/spls.xml?published_date=2016-07-10&published_date_comparison=gte</current_url>
   <previous_page>null</previous_page>
   <previous_page_url>null</previous_page_url>
   <next_page>2</next_page>
   <next_page_url>https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v2/spls.xml?published_date=2016-07-10&published_date_comparison=gte&page=2&pagesize=100</next_page_url>
   <db_published_date>Aug 23, 2016 05:14:15PM EST</db_published_date>
 </metadata>
-<spl>
  <setid>029acfa1-81f0-490c-ad46-ec6f19591293</setid>
  <spl_version>3</spl_version>
  <title>QUETIAPINE FUMARATE TABLET [REMEDYREPACK INC.]</title>
  <published_date>Aug 23, 2016</published_date>
 </spl>

-<spl>
  <setid>02cdae31-5b23-452b-9046-7819ef51f3ed</setid>
  <spl_version>1</spl_version>
  <title>LISINOPRIL TABLET [CARDINAL HEALTH]</title>
  <published_date>Aug 23, 2016</published_date>
 </spl>
```

Now I want to parse this XML into my custom object which is as follow

```
class spl
{
   public string setid { get; set; }
   public string spl_version { get; set; }
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string published_date { get; set; } 
}
```

So my linq should return me a list of **SPL** which contains all values of its properties.

I tried something like this:

```
xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

IEnumerable<spl> result = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("spls")
                          select new spl()
                          {
                              setid = (string)c.Attribute("setid"),
                              spl_version = (string)c.Attribute("spl_version"),
                              title = (string)c.Attribute("title"),
                              published_date = (string)c.Attribute("published_date")
                          };
```

Comment: you could have deserialized the xml to C# typed object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes in your linq:

1. In the `Descendants` method you specify the name of the element you are looking for. So `spl` instead of `spls`.
2. The values you want for the object are elements and not attributes so use `c.Element(...)` instead of `c.Attribute(...)`

So:

```
var result = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("spl")
             select new spl()
             {
                 setid = c.Element("setid").Value,
                 spl_version = c.Element("spl_version").Value,
                 title = c.Element("title").Value,
                 published_date = c.Element("published_date").Value
             };
```

Comment: @rahularyansharma - Happy it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

refer link
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/reading-xml-file-through-linq-a-few-tips/

```
xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

IEnumerable<spl> result = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("spl")
                          select new spl()
                          {
                              setid = (string)c.Elements("setid"),
                              spl_version = (string)c.Elements("spl_version"),
                              title = (string)c.Elements("title"),
                              published_date = (string)c.Elements("published_date")
                          };
```